# Ansible (module filesystem): Device item not found

Tags: hadoop, filesystems, ansible

When trying to create a list of filesystems with Ansible module "filesystem", I hit the following error message:

> failed: [host] (item=/dev/sdb) => {"failed": true, "item": "/dev/sdb", "msg": "Device item not found."}

I have verified that `/dev/sdb` exists on the target "host", so I don't understand the Ansible error message:

```
[~]# ls -l /dev/sdb
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 16 Mar  1 09:06 /dev/sdb
```

Here is the definition of my task:

```
- name: Create /grid* filesystems using "hadoop" options defined in /etc/mke2fs.conf
  filesystem:
    fstype: ext4
    dev: item
    opts: -T hadoop
  with_items: "{{ grid_block_devices }}"
```

```
[~]# cat roles/mke2fs/vars/main.yml 
---
grid_block_devices: [ '/dev/sdb','/dev/sdc','/dev/sdd','/dev/sde','/dev/sdf','/dev/sdg','/dev/sdh','/dev/sdi','/dev/sdj','/dev/sdk','/dev/sdl','/dev/sdm','/dev/sdn','/dev/sdo','/dev/sdp' ]
```

Does someone know where is the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a Jinja2 expression to refer to a variable value, otherwise you assign a string `item` to the `dev` parameter. The error message is:

> Device **item** not found.

It cannot find a device named `item`.

Fix it this way:

```
- name: Create /grid* filesystems using "hadoop" options defined in /etc/mke2fs.conf
  filesystem:
    fstype: ext4
    dev: "{{ item }}"
    opts: -T hadoop
  with_items: "{{ grid_block_devices }}"
```

Comment: Ho yes with "{{ item }}" it works indeed. { item } was not working. Thanks a lot !